# scanf("...%n",...) on failing match

Tags: c, scanf

I want to count the "columns" in a CSV files, given its elements' string pattern e.g.

```
   1,2,3,4
```

with pattern "%d," should return 4.

I wrote a tokenizer like this

```
offset = 0;
strcpy(var_pattern, pattern) // e.g. pattern = "%d," 
strcat(var_pattern, "%n")
while (sscanf(&line[offset], LINE_SIZE, buf,var_pattern,&bytes_consumed > 0) {
      count++; // column counter
      offset += bytes_consumed
};
```

the problem I have is the missing delimiter, ',' in the example, for the last element in the CSV file row. On linux64/gcc doing

```
    c = sscanf("12","%d,%n",&a,&b)
```

gives  c= 1 (number of patterns matched), a=12 and b=32767 (bytes consumed). Is this (idiotic) behaviour standard/platform specific? Or a bug?

I know about strtok or regular-expression packaged, but I would have liked to use a standard method, and the idea of using strtok makes my inner software engineer puke.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is difficult, easier is:

```
char *s="1,2,3,4";
int n,i;
while( 1==sscanf(s,"%d%n",&i,&n) && (s+=n,*s==','?++s:!*s) )
  printf("%d\n",i);
```